I am doing Feature Transformation of my Target column using Function Transformer , But I am not able to get Idea how to pass it to the function?
The code is to take my Target column which is Time_taken(min) having values as (min) 36, (min) 54, (min) 65 ... so on. so i want to create a new column "Time Taken" which will have values 36,54,65....and delete the Time_taken(min) using Function Transformers.
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

class TimeTakenTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, input_column):
        self.input_column = input_column
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X = X.copy()
        op = []
        for i in X[self.input_column]:
            a = i.split()
            op.append(int(a[1]))
        X['Time_taken'] = op
        X.drop([self.input_column], axis=1, inplace=True)
        return X

Target_column = Pipeline([('Replacing Values', TimeTakenTransformer(input_column="TARGET_COLUMN_NAME"))])

Target_column = Pipeline([('Replacing Values', TimeTakenTransformer(input_column="TARGET_COLUMN_NAME"))])


TARGET_COLUMN_NAME = "Time_taken(min)"  # Assuming this is the correct column name

# Assuming df is your DataFrame, apply the transformation
df_transformed = Target_column.fit_transform(df[[TARGET_COLUMN_NAME]])

# Replace the original column with the transformed one
df["Time_Taken"] = df_transformed

I am not able to Identify the correct ways to pass the input. How to solve this issue?
